# GitLab CI/CD Android AAB

Tags: android, gitlab-ci

В GitLab, Pipeline Editor, если следующий код для сборки приложения. Как мне сделать абы на выходе получать не APK, а AAB файл, пригодный для отправки в Google Play?

```
stages:
  - build

.build_template:
  stage: build
  image: thyrlian/android-sdk:7.1
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/apk/
    expose_as: apk
    expire_in: 1 week
  before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
    - export VERSION=$(date "+%y%m")-${CI_PIPELINE_IID}
    - echo $VERSION
    - ./gradlew :app:assemble$APP_NAME
  cache:
    paths:
      - .gradle/wrapper
      - .gradle/caches

debug:
  extends: .build_template
  variables:
    APP_NAME: Debug
  when: manual

internal:
  extends: .build_template
  variables:
    APP_NAME: Internal
  when: manual

release:
  extends: .build_template
  variables:
    APP_NAME: Release
  when: manual
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204818/5479247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить AAB файл, пригодный для отправки в Google Play, вам необходимо в скрипте заменить команду `./gradlew :app:assemble$APP_NAME` на `./gradlew :app:bundle$APP_NAME`. Это запустит команду сборки, которая создаст AAB файл в папке `app/build/outputs/bundle/`.

Вам также нужно изменить путь для хранения артефактов на `app/build/outputs/bundle/`, чтобы он мог быть загружен и использован в дальнейшем.

```
stages:
  - build

.build_template:
  stage: build
  image: thyrlian/android-sdk:7.1
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/bundle/
    expose_as: aab
    expire_in: 1 week
  before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
    - export VERSION=$(date "+%y%m")-${CI_PIPELINE_IID}
    - echo $VERSION
    - ./gradlew :app:bundle$APP_NAME
  cache:
    paths:
      - .gradle/wrapper
      - .gradle/caches

debug
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает!))